# Overcoming schemas/columns inconsistency across datasets

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I've found out that same fields/columns have different business context for certain regions in my dataset.

I have few markets but lets take for sample example - GB and US. Most of those columns have the same meaning, but there are pairs which not, like:

`SB1 for US is Strength Evaluation`

`SB2 for US is Power Evaluation`

while

`SB1 for GB is Power Evaluation`

`SB2 for GB is Strength Evaluation`

and its case in whole dataset that one country SB1 is Power SB2 strength, for another its reversed and so on. Ideally looking for advice in PySpark, but while I will be working in Databricks, SQL may do as well.

My silver layer looks like that

| ID | Market | CK | SB1 | SB2 | SbX | ColX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | 1US | 2 | 1 | 9 | 9 |
| 2 | US | 2US | 2 | 2 | 9 | 9 |
| 3 | US | 3US | 1 | 1 | 9 | 9 |
| 1 | GB | 1GB | 3 | 5 | 9 | 9 |
| 2 | GB | 2GB | 4 | 4 | 9 | 9 |
| 3 | GB | 3GB | 5 | 3 | 9 | 9 |

What is expected output in that scenario I guess is (look at SB1 SB2 cols)

| ID | Market | CK | SB1 | SB2 | SbX | ColX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | 1US | 2 | 1 | 9 | 9 |
| 2 | US | 2US | 2 | 2 | 9 | 9 |
| 3 | US | 3US | 1 | 1 | 9 | 9 |
| 1 | GB | 1GB | 5 | 3 | 9 | 9 |
| 2 | GB | 2GB | 4 | 4 | 9 | 9 |
| 3 | GB | 3GB | 3 | 5 | 9 | 9 |

Each dataset got over 50 columns, and there are almost 10 markets

Any protips, ideas how to handle that? I guess it can't be solved on ingestion level, so raw and curated zone is not the place to make it happen I guess, the curated dataset has to be transformed and values filled accordingly

Comment: "I guess it can't be solved on ingestion level" why not?

Comment: The rule is that the raw zone/bronze should reflect the way the "real" data is? Whatever is it, whether its some anomaly or not, it has been conducted this way? Or I can break that rule? If yes, how would you approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely use standard SQL feature - `CASE..WHEN` as follows:

```
select id, market, ck,
       case market when 'US' then SB1
                   when 'GB' then SB2
       end as SB1,
       case market when 'US' then SB2
                   when 'GB' then SB1
       end as SB2,
       sbx, colx
  from your_table
```

Alternatively, You can also use `UNION ALL` as follows:

```
select id, market, ck, sb1, sb2, sbx, colx from your_table where market = 'US'
UNION ALL
select id, market, ck, sb2, sb1, sbx, colx from your_table where market = 'GB'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of the same, however I already have lets say limited numbers of studies for each market, but can't control how much there will be, so more reasonable seems second option? Also I have to check whether it can be done from dataset where all markets are consolidated

Comment: Wow. It turned out that not only its by market, but by individual study.. assuming I can replace market with study_id, how can I assure continous integration? If some new study appears, I'd need to readjust a code everytime.. is there any way? Or should I create a new thread for that

Comment: In SO, You have to ask each question individually. You can mark this question as done by accepting the answer and create a new question.(Start new thread)